# jQuery chaining performance

Tags: jquery, performance, chaining

Are these equivalent in term of speed ?

```
$(this).attr("date",date);
$(this).attr("date_start",date_start);
$(this).attr("heure_start",heure_start);
```

or

```
$(this).attr("date",date).attr("date_start",date_start).attr("heure_start",heure_start);
```

Even if the second is faster is it better to write it separate to make the code more readable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, the two aren't equivalent in speed.

`$(this)` builds a new jQuery object each time. And depending on what is `this`, this can be a complex operation.

So the second form is faster.

Note that for readibility you can write it as

```
$(this)
    .attr("date",date)
    .attr("date_start",date_start)
    .attr("heure_start",heure_start);
```

If you can't chain the operations because you have other lines of code in between, you can also cache the object. This is usual :

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.attr("date", date);
$this.attr("date_start", date_start);
$this.attr("heure_start", heure_start);
```

And note also that [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can take a map as argument :

```
$(this).attr({
    date: date,
    date_start: date_start,
    heure_start: heure_start
});
```

Comment: Thats a complete explanation!

Answer (score 5):

For readability purposes you could split the line to

```
$(this)
    .attr("date",date)
    .attr("date_start",date_start)
    .attr("heure_start",heure_start);
```

I know this should have been a comment but the spacing would have made no sense as one.